# count specific character at curl output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Output from `curl` in my Bash is :

```
object(\Response\)#1399 (3) {
  ["httpResponse"]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#1084 (6) {
    ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
    string(2) "OK"
    ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
    int(200)
    ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
    array(11) {
     ....
     ....
     ....
     ....
    ["status"]=>
    string(2) "ok"
  }
}
```

My Code is :

```
while read ID; do
curl  -X -d "http://localhost/new.php?media_id="$ID"&submit=Submit"

done < ~/ids.txt
```

Also i add this :

```
curl -s  -X -d "http://localhost/new.php?media_id="$ID"&submit=Submit" | grep -c 'string(2) "ok"'
```

and out put was `1` . i want it count all output and show me example `Success : 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `grep -c`:

```
f=0
s=0
while read ID; do
    var=$(curl  -X -d "http://localhost/new.php?media_id="$ID"&submit=Submit")
    grep -q 'string(2) "ok"' <<<"$var" && ((s++))
    grep -q 'string(2) "notok"' <<<"$var" && ((f++))
    echo "$var"
done < ~/ids.txt
echo "Success : $s"
echo "Failed : $f"
```

Comment: i'm using while read ID; do and then curl now how it can count in loop ?

Comment: @Mehran: I've updated my answer

Comment: when i run my script im not see anything on output ...

Comment: You don't even see `Success : 0`?

Comment: What if you run the code I have suggested for you to run?

Comment: its work on terminal but on my script you suggest not work

Comment: what hashbang are you using for your script?  Also the example in the comment you deleted was not the code I had suggested...

Comment: #!/bin/bash i used and also i remove -s on curl and   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5877  100  5877    0     0   3021      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3021

Comment: oh at the end it finish i see Success : 4

Comment: @Mehran: Is that what you wanted or are you wanting to see all the curl output as well?

Comment: yes i want see all output as well @Jesse_b

Comment: @Mehran: I've updated my answer again.